# How to convert multiple greyscale images to color on same page?

Tags: html, css, svg-filters, grayscale

I am trying to implement this code which displays an image to greyscale and changes the image to its original colour image on hover. The issue here is for svg inline it is not working for IE10. The piece of code for Firefox, Safari, Chrome works, the code for IE10 (svg) does not. Can someone please help me solve this issue?

HTML Code:
`

Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE6-9

```
<p>IE10 with inline SVG</p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svgroot" viewBox="0 0 216 135" width="216" height="135">
<defs>
     <filter id="filtersPicture">
       <feComposite result="inputTo_38" in="SourceGraphic" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="0" k4="0" />
       <feColorMatrix id="filter_38" type="saturate" values="0" data-filterid="38" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <image filter="url(&quot;#filtersPicture&quot;)" x="0" y="0" width="216" height="135" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="cloud.png" /><br />


  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svgroot1" viewBox="0 0 216 135" width="216" height="135">
  <defs>
     <filter id="filtersPicture">
       <feComposite result="inputTo_38" in="SourceGraphic" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="0" k4="0" />
       <feColorMatrix id="filter_38" type="saturate" values="0" data-filterid="38" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <image filter="url(&quot;#filtersPicture&quot;)" x="0" y="0" width="216" height="135" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="sd.png" />`
```

css code is :

`img.grayscale {
        filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'>#grayscale");

```
    filter: gray; 
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
-webkit-transition: all .6s ease; /* Fade to color for Chrome and Safari */
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Fix for transition flickering */
}

img.grayscale:hover {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}

svg {
    background:url(cloud.png);
}



svg image {
    transition: all .6s ease;
}

svg image:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}`
```

how do i make it multiple greyscale images on same page in svg code.